# Reply with hero card in after form method in Bot Framework c#

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have dialog from which I am starting form and I would like to display hero card after form is completed by user. I am starting the form with code below and also assigning the after form method.

```
var startFormDialog = Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(StartForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart));    
context.Call<StartForm>(startFormDialog,AfterMenuForm);

//AfterMenuForm method implementation
private async Task AfterMenuForm(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<StartForm> result)
{
    message = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
    Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Should go to conversation, with a hero card");
     replyToConversation.Recipient = message.From;
     replyToConversation.Type = "message";
     replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
     //List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
     replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "carousel";
     List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
     CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
     {
         Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin",
         Type = "openUrl",
         Title = "WikiPedia Page"
     };
     cardButtons.Add(plButton);
     HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
     {
         Title = "I'm a hero card",
         Subtitle = "Pig Latin Wikipedia Page",
         //Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons
      };
      Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
      replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
      await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
}
```

The problem is, that in order to be able to send Hero Card answer to user, I need activity object and this is not available in AfterMenuForm method. Is there a way how to surface the activity object within this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IDialogContext` to create a new `IMessageActivity` and send a `HeroCard`.

Try `context.MakeMessage();`. Once you have the message you can just use it to send the card. You don't need to do CreateReply over that message, it's not necessary.

Also, depending the scenario, you might what to access to the original activity. That's available on `context.Activity`.

Finally, I'm not sure why you are using Chain.From; you should be just using:

```
var startFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(StartForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart));    
context.Call<StartForm>(startFormDialog,AfterMenuForm);
```

Comment: Hi @EzequielJadib, I tried MakeMessage() method already, however I got this exception when trying to PostAsync the HeroCard.: {"'activityId' cannot be null."} . Apparently the activity is not present within the context when the callback AfterMenuForm method is called. Moreover context.Activity property does not exist within the IDialogContext. Please is there any other way to solve this? I have added AfterMenuForm method implementation to original post. And also thanks for advice with Chain.Form.

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder nuget are u using? You don't need to do the CreateReply. Just use the message created with MakeMessage. Yo don't need to fill the recipient either

Comment: Thank you Ezequiel. I am using v 3.0. It worked when I used the message obtained from MakeMessage without CreateReply. Please add this comment to your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer. Consider updating to v3.5.5